# Symfony2 TokenStorage is always empty in Behat FeatureContext

Tags: symfony, behat

I've set up Behat with Symfony2Extension in order to start testing the application.

Having set up the SF2Extension, I'm able to inject Symofny services into my Behat Context:

```
contexts:
    - My\AppBundle\Features\Security\Context\FeatureContext:
        session:    '@session'
        tokenStorage:   '@security.token_storage'
```

The FeatureContext's constructor:

`public function __construct(Session $session, TokenStorage $tokenStorage)`

Now the problem that I cannot overcome is that `$tokenStorage` is always empty when the tests/scenarios are executing (they're executing with Selenium in a normal browser). My scenarios have a user log-in to the SF2 application successfully, so there exists a token and a non-empty TokenStorage.

Although the `$tokenStorage` object is injected into the Context, it seems to have nothing to do with the actual application being run at the moment - it's always empty.

I'd appreciate your advice. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to access the token storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service that's injected by Behat into your context is not the same as the one used by your application. Behat boots its own instance of the Symfony service container. Since you haven't executed the authentication process in your Behat context, the authentication token wasn't created.

Since you use the selenium driver, you don't really use the Symfony extension to make requests and you don't have access to the application other then through its UI (html).

Even if you used the Symfony2Extension to make requests (by configuring the symfony2 driver), it boots a new instance of the container on each request. What you'd be able to do is to access the Symfony profiler, which might provide you some of the information you need.

Comment: Well I need to test if certain users have the expected role in the application after logging-in. It did make much sens to me to emulate and manipulate session and TokenStorate programmatically since I used Selenium to go through user paths- I was wrong perhaps. I have a scenario where a user logs-in through Selenium. I now ant to check his ROLE. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: As I said you use a driver that only has access to the user interface, so your verifications are limited to inspecting the user interface. You could try loading the session (you've got the cookie), but all of this kind of solutions are hackish.